# SignalR: This web page has a redirect loop

Tags: signalr

I'm trying to deploy a SignalR web app onto an on-premises server.  The server is running on Windows 7 Ultimate, IIS Version 7.5.7600.16385.

The app is working without a problem on my laptop, using IIS Express.

This is the latest version of SignalR, which generates its own signalr.html page for debugging hubs.  In that page on the server, I added a call to `$.connection.hub.logging = true;` before the call to `$.connection.hub.start();`.

The output looks like this.

```
[16:22:49 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'notificationhub'. jquery.signalr-2.0.0.min.js:8
[16:22:49 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3'. jquery.signalr-2.0.0.min.js:8
[16:22:49 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://192.168.2.9/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionTok…HBFdOC&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&tid=6'. jquery.signalr-2.0.0.min.js:8
[16:22:49 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close(). jquery.signalr-2.0.0.min.js:8
[16:22:49 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: This browser supports SSE, skipping Forever Frame. jquery.signalr-2.0.0.min.js:8
GET http://192.168.2.9/signalr/Error.htm  jquery.signalr-2.0.0.min.js:8
[16:22:50 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Opening long polling request to 'http://192.168.2.9/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=Ck…BFdOC&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&tid=10'. jquery.signalr-2.0.0.min.js:8
[16:22:50 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection. jquery.signalr-2.0.0.min.js:8
[16:22:50 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true. jquery.signalr-2.0.0.min.js:8
[16:22:50 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: LongPolling failed to connect. jquery.signalr-2.0.0.min.js:8
GET http://192.168.2.9/signalr/Error.htm  jquery.js:8706
GET http://192.168.2.9/signalr/Error.htm
```

When I copy the links `http://192.168.2.9/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&...` and `http://192.168.2.9/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&...` and paste them into a separate browser window, I get a redirect loop onto the SignalR error page.

Am I missing any obvious debugging steps?

EDIT: Running those queries through Fiddler shows me that the /signalr/connect links are redirecting to login.aspx:

```
1   302 HTTP    192.168.2.9 /signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=OcIKZ%2FgRaOBwdEp6gMtBmoflJkIWwcsfsjIU%2BznksMqCFTPAYkaQ1MDEihovbCgh4MnIuB9F6nJPELk8VAn7K2sqN9CXbhu%2FlwLEBWVTaUTYAEOE&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&tid=2  699 no-cache; Expires: -1   text/html; charset=utf-8                
2   302 HTTP    192.168.2.9 /login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=OcIKZ%252FgRaOBwdEp6gMtBmoflJkIWwcsfsjIU%252BznksMqCFTPAYkaQ1MDEihovbCgh4MnIuB9F6nJPELk8VAn7K2sqN9CXbhu%252FlwLEBWVTaUTYAEOE&connectionData=%255B%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522notificationhub%2522%257D%255D&tid=2&transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=OcIKZ/gRaOBwdEp6gMtBmoflJkIWwcsfsjIU+znksMqCFTPAYkaQ1MDEihovbCgh4MnIuB9F6nJPELk8VAn7K2sqN9CXbhu/lwLEBWVTaUTYAEOE&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22:%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&tid=2  138 private text/html; charset=utf-8
```

So this must be something to do with the connection token.  Still more investigation needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

302 errors can mean that you already have content where SignalR is expecting to see its hub. One troubleshooting step would be to manually generate the proxy instead, so you'll have more control over what gets created where.  See the following:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting#other

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#genproxy

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  It was actually forwarding the request to the site's error page.  Good tip though.  I'll make a note of it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your connectionData parameter is encoded twice when redirect to login.aspx. It is

```
connectionData=%255B%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522notificationhub%2522%257D%255D
```

but have to be

```
%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D
```

, which is `[{"name":"notificationhub"}]`.
Can you give more details what error exactly you receive?